# Avoid SOQL 100 error by querying outside of the loop

Tags: apex, salesforce-id, controller

I'm currently running a program which limits a query to 95 items in order to avoid the SOQL 100 queries error. THe relevant snippet of the program looks like this:

```
while(x!=0){        
                String prod='MAR-'+ass[x-1].Product_Code__c;//Format for maintenance on assets is MAR-ProductCode
            newProds[x-1]=[Select id,ProductCode,UnitPrice,Product2.Description from PricebookEntry where ProductCode=:prod.trim() AND Pricebook2Id=Pricebook2Id.Id LIMIT 95];//selecting Fields from Pricebook for all the Maintenance products only and store it in the last row.
```

I'm trying to avoid having it query inside the loop and thus I am doing the following:

```
     Prods =[SELECT ID
                               ,ProductCode
                               ,UnitPrice
                               ,Product2.Description
                               FROM
                                    PricebookEntry 
                                    WHERE 

                                        Pricebook2Id=Pricebook2Id.Id


                              ];

     List <PricebookEntry> newProdsList = Prods;
     newProds=new PricebookEntry[SelectedAssets.size()];


     x=SelectedAssets.size() ;

             while(x!=0){//where x is the size of the getSelectedAssets List       

                 String prod='MAR-'+SelectedAssets[x-1].Product_Code__c;

             newProds[x-1]=[Id=newProdsList.Id, ProductCode=prod, UnitPrice=newProdsList.UnitPrice, Product2.Description=newProdsList.Product2.Description]

x--;
}
```

Will the above method allow me to avoid the SOQL query error? Am I making any kind of mistakes in my logic here? I'm querying everything outside of the loop, putting it in a list and then I'll just be iterating through the list to populate the newProds Pricebook Item. Will it populate the newProds correctly and match the id with each of the ProductCode,UnitPrice and Product2.Description?

Comment: Have you tried it? What makes you think it won't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to query **all** the PriceBookEntry records in one query rather than inside the while loop.

The following is the general idea. Use a `Set` to build up a collection of records you are interested in and then use an `in` where clause with the Set.

```
Set<string> productCodes = new Set<string>();
for (Asset__c a : SelectedAssets) {
    productCodes.add(a.Product_Code__c);
}

List <PricebookEntry> newProds = [Select id, ProductCode, UnitPrice, Product2.Description 
    from PricebookEntry 
    where ProductCode in :productCodes AND Pricebook2Id = Pricebook2Id.Id];

// Additional steps if ordering is important
Map<string, PricebookEntry> productCodeToPricebookEntryMap = 
    new Map<string, PricebookEntry>();
for(PricebookEntry pbe : newProds) {
    productCodeToPricebookEntryMap.add(pbe.ProductCode, pbe);
}

interger x = SelectedAssets.size() - 1;

while(x >= 0) {
    string prod = 'MAR-'+SelectedAssets[x].Product_Code__c;

    if(productCodeToPricebookEntryMap.containsKey(prod)) {
        PricebookEntry pbe = productCodeToPricebookEntryMap.get(prod);
        // Do something with the pbe
    }
    x--;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. how would using a set help in this situation? From what I'm gathering online, a set is an *unordered* collection. However, I need it to be ordered so that I can map the right PricebookEntry Id to the right fields.

Here's the line: newProds[x-1]=[Id=newProdsList.Id, ProductCode=prod, UnitPrice=newProdsList.UnitPrice, Product2.Description=newProdsList.Product2.Description]

Comment: The `Set` allows you to query all the required PricebookEntry records in one go. If ordering is important you can then build a Map that the while loop can pull the correct record from.